# Copy Text From an Opened URL in Python

Tags: python, json, url

So I'm trying to read a web page on the internet, it works but it gives me the whole page, I want to copy a specific word from it, not more.
Basically an API URL like this, `http://api.formice.com/tribe/stats.json?n=Safwanrockz`
What if I wanted to copy the "rank" value only?
This is my code:

```
import shutil
import os
import time
import datetime
import math
import urllib
from array import array

filehandle = urllib.urlopen('http://api.formice.com/tribe/stats.json?n=Safwanrockz')

for lines in filehandle.readlines():
print lines

filehandle.close()
```

Comment: The link doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: It's just a normal text which I want to copy. Even if it includes the "Tribe not found".

Comment: Can you provide example responses and what you would like extracted from each?

Comment: For example, in this link http://api.formice.com/mouse/stats.json?n=Safwanrockz I want it to extract the "Tribe" value where it says "Three Feathers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load it via `json.loads()` into python `dict`:

```
import json
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.formice.com/mouse/stats.json?n=Safwanrockz')
data = json.loads(response.read())

print type(data)  # prints <type 'dict'>

print data['tribe']  # prints "Three Feathers"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main alternatives:

1. Decoding the JSON object using the standard `json` module (or similar).
2. Using a regular expression.

I'd recommend the first alternative because it's more structured and stable, and would work if your requirements get more complex.

Comment: Hmm, any guide of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
import json

data = urllib.urlopen('http://api.formice.com/tribe/stats.json?n=Safwanrockz').read()
json_data = json.loads(data)
print data
print json_data['error']
```

Here `data` is the raw data from the document, and `json_data` is the JSON-parsed document (parsed as a dictionary). The first `print` statement prints the raw data. The second prints the value of the JSON element `error`.